# Close a tag with no text in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to output a XML file using Python and lxml

However, I notice one thing that if a tag has no text, it does not close itself. An example of this would be:

```
root = etree.Element('document')
rootTree = etree.ElementTree(root)
firstChild = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')
```

The output of this is:

```
<document>
<test/>
</document
```

I want the output to be:

```
<document>
<test>
</test>
</document>
```

So basically I want to close a tag which has no text, but is used to the attribute value. How do I do that? And also, what is such a tag called? I would have Googled it, but I don't know how to search for it.

Comment: Can't you set the value to a newline? That would mean that `test` will have a child node of type text with value `\n`.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't know that <test> </test> is equivalent to <test/> and that it is an accepted norm to do so. Frank has answered my question, but if need arises I can always use \n.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `<test></test>` and `<test/>` mean exactly the same thing. What you want is for the test-tag to actually do have a text that consists in a single linebreak. However, an empty tag with no text is usually written as `<test/>` and it makes very little sense to insist on it to appear as `<test></test>`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I was not aware of that. I thought to maintain consistency, if a tag had no text but had some attribute, it was mandatory to close it.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify @ymv answer in case it might be of help to others:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('document')
rootTree = etree.ElementTree(root)
firstChild = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')

print(etree.tostring(root, method='html'))
### b'<document><test></test></document>'
```

Comment: More simpler, if you want jQuery to parse custom elements properly.

Answer (score 3):

Use lxml.html.tostring to serialize to HTML

```
import lxml.html
root = lxml.html.fromstring(mydocument)
print(lxml.html.tostring(root))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use empty string '' like this:

```
root = etree.Element('document')
etree.SubElement(root, 'test').text = ''
```