# Python lxml objectify - How to create elements with a dash

Tags: python, lxml

I have a need to use lxml's objectify module to create some xml elements that have a dash in them. For example:

```
<program-id>$Id: myFile.py 3519 2012-07-17 13:37:20Z $</program-id>
<formatter-txt>basic format</formatter-txt>
```

I can't find any references online about how to do this and when I try to just do it in Python, it's a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the documentation [here](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) as I've never used objectify:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> doc = objectify.E.xml()
>>> doc.append(getattr(objectify.E,'program-id')("$Id: myFile.py 3519 2012-07-17 13:37:20Z $"))
>>> doc.append(getattr(objectify.E,'formatter-text')("basic format"))
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
<xml xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <program-id py:pytype="str">$Id: myFile.py 3519 2012-07-17 13:37:20Z $</program-id>
  <formatter-text py:pytype="str">basic format</formatter-text>
</xml>
```

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but do you know how to force lxml to output "<foo></foo>" instead of "<foo/>" for empty elements?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I'm not sure that it is possible with lxml and xml. They are equivalent in content terms. If you absolutely need it, I'd imagine one way of achieving it would to be to use text placeholder or entity under `<foo>`. E.g. `<foo>|</foo>` and then stripping it out of the xml after you've rendered it to a string. Hacky.

Comment: Here's an answer to more-or-less the same question as your empty-tag question here in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771410/267781

Comment: I know they're the same. Sadly my generated XML is not being parsed by a third party. Instead, they're just reading it in line by line and for whatever reason, they won't fix their script to accept XML without a specific closing tag. Thanks though!