# Override lxml behavior to write a closing and opening element for Null tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

```
root = etree.Element('document')
rootTree = etree.ElementTree(root)
firstChild = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')
```

The output is:

```
<document>
<test/>
</document
```

I want the output to be:

```
<document>
<test>
</test>
</document>
```

I know both are equivalent but is there a way to get the output that i want .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `method` argument of `tostring` to `html`.  As in:

```
etree.tostring(root, method="html")
```

Reference:  [Close a tag with no text in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972801/912215)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do it:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('document')
rootTree = etree.ElementTree(root)
firstChild = etree.SubElement(root, 'test')

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

# Set empty string as element content to force open and close tags
firstChild.text = ''

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<document>
  <test/>
</document>

<document>
  <test></test>
</document>
```