# lxml: keep the same tags in fromstring and tostring

Tags: python, xml, lxml, tostring

I'm using lxml to parse an XML message. What I want to do is convert the string into an xml message, extract some informations thanks to xpath directives, edit a few attributes and then dump the XML into a string again.

lxml is doing a wonderful job at it, except for one thing : It won't respect the tag declaration that were originally provided. What I mean by this, is that if in your input you have :

```
xml_str = "<root><tag><tutu/></tag></root>"
```

or

```
xml_str = "<root><tag><tutu></tutu></tag></root>"
```

The following code will return the same thing:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.XML(xml_str)
>>> print etree.tostring(root)
<root><tag><tutu/></tag></root>
```

The tutu tag will be rendered no matter what as <tutu/>

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543399/override-lxml-behavior-to-write-a-closing-and-opening-element-for-null-tags) that by setting the text of the element to '' we can force the closing tag to be explicitly rendered.

My issue is the following : I need to have the exact same tag rendering before and after calling lxml (because some external program will perform a string comparison on both strings and a mismatch will be detected on <tutu/> and <tutu></tutu>)

I know we can create a custom ElementTree class as well as a custom parser...What I was thinking was while parsing the string, to save in the custom ElementTree what type of tag we have (short or extended) and then before calling tostring function, update the tree and set the text to None or '' to keep the same type of tag as in the input

The question is : How may I know what type of tag I have? Or do you have any other idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for your help