# XML pretty print fails in Python lxml

Tags: xml, python-2.7, lxml, pretty-print

I am trying to read, modify, and write an XML file with lxml 4.1.1 in Python 2.7.6.

My code:

```
import lxml.etree as et

fn_xml_in = 'in.xml'
parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_doc = et.parse(fn_xml_in, parser)
xml_doc.getroot().find('b').append(et.Element('c'))
xml_doc.write('out.xml', method='html', pretty_print=True)
```

The input file `in.xml` looks like this:

```
<a>
    <b/>
</a>
```

And the produced output file `out.xml`:

```
<a>
    <b><c></c></b>
</a>
```

Or when I set `remove_blank_text=True`:

```
<a><b><c></c></b></a>
```

I would have expected lxml to insert line breaks and indentation within the `b` element:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c></c>
    </b>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this?

I have tried some `tidy` lib wrappers, but they seem to specialize on HTML rather than XML.

I have also tried to add newline characters as `b`'s `tail`, but then even the indentation is broken.

**Edit:** I need the `c` element to remain separated in an opening and a closing tag: `<c></c>`. This is why I use `method='HTML'` in the example.

Comment: Remove `method='html'` or use `method='xml'`.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me towards a proper solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "xml" output method when writing (that's the default so it does not have to be given explicitly).

Set the `text` property of the `c` element to an empty string to ensure that the element gets serialized as `<c></c>`.

Code:

```
import lxml.etree as et

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_doc = et.parse('in.xml', parser)

b = xml_doc.getroot().find('b')
c = et.Element('c')
c.text=''
b.append(c)

xml_doc.write('out.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

Result (out.xml):

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c></c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mzjn's comment, I found a working – but not elegant – solution. Since I need empty elements to remain in HTML syntax, the mere use of `method='XML'` is not satisfying.

Formatting the document twice yields the desired result:

```
import lxml.etree as et

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_doc = et.parse('in.xml', parser)
xml_doc.getroot().find('b').append(et.Element('c'))
xml_doc.write('out.xml', pretty_print=True)

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=False)
xml_doc = et.parse('out.xml', parser)
xml_doc.write('out.xml', pretty_print=True, method='HTML')
```

results in:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c></c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Not elegant, but working.

Comment: Instead of parsing the document twice, you could set the `text` property of the `c` element to an empty string. That will ensure that the element gets serialized as `<c></c>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548368/407651.

Comment: Wonderful! The difference between an empty string and nothing at all. Would you care to turn your comments into an answer? I would rather accept yours than mine.