# Missing end tag for some elements when writing XML to file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i want to use xml.etree.ElmentTree to parser a xml to change value then write to a new file, but if the tag with None text value, after i write to a new xml, the right tag will lost:

Below is the orignal content:

```
<LignesReception>

    <CodeBarre>3607171442485</CodeBarre>
    <QteRecue>8</QteRecue>
    <QteRecue1Choix>8</QteRecue1Choix>
    <QteRecue2Choix>0</QteRecue2Choix>
    <DateLivraisonPrevue>14022019</DateLivraisonPrevue>
    <QteRetourneeFourn></QteRetourneeFourn>
    <CodeCauseRetourFourn></CodeCauseRetourFourn>
    <PxAchatInitial></PxAchatInitial>
    <PxAchatModifie></PxAchatModifie>
    <QteAnnoncee>8</QteAnnoncee>
    <QteEnEchantillon></QteEnEchantillon>
    <QteAttDecision>0</QteAttDecision>
</LignesReception>
```

Blow is the content after i write to a new xml file:

```
<LignesReception>

    <CodeBarre>3607171442485</CodeBarre>
    <QteRecue>8</QteRecue>
    <QteRecue1Choix>8</QteRecue1Choix>
    <QteRecue2Choix>0</QteRecue2Choix>
    <DateLivraisonPrevue>27022019</DateLivraisonPrevue>
    <QteRetourneeFourn />
    <CodeCauseRetourFourn />
    <PxAchatInitial />
    <PxAchatModifie />
    <QteAnnoncee>8</QteAnnoncee>
    <QteEnEchantillon />
    <QteAttDecision>0</QteAttDecision>
</LignesReception>
```

Here is my script:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith("xml"):
        tree = ET.parse(file)
        for i in tree.iter():
            if i.text is None:
                i.text = ""
            if i.tag == "DateLivraisonPrevue":
                i.text = "27022019"
        tree.write("New xml.xml",encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
```

can anyone help to on this issue to fix the xml format write, thanks!

Comment: Setting `i.text = ""` (empty string) when `i.text == None` is a workaround that works with lxml (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47817478/407651). But unfortunately it does not work with ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

The right tag is not lost.

```
<QteRetourneeFourn></QteRetourneeFourn>
```

is the same tag (from xml perspective) as

```
<QteRetourneeFourn />
```

Comment: Yes, the representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags.